# Hide play button on facebook chat

Tags: facebook, chat, messenger, facebook-instant-games

I created a facebook instant app with a chatbot. The chatbot works fine. The chatbot should launch a facebook instant game. This works fine on mobile phones, but after assigning the game to the page, it is no longer possible to chat with the page on desktop devices. The play button is overlapping the chatbox and you can not send messages. Is it possible to remove the play button?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instant Games bots have only a play button by default. You can override the default experience by modifying the persistent menu. To enable users to communicate with the bot, specifically look into `composer_input_disabled`.

Documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messenger-profile-api/persistent-menu/